# Fourier transform of $x \mapsto e^{x}e^{-e^x}$

Tags: integration, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

I don't even know where to start to tackle this integral: $$\int_{\mathbb{R}} \exp\left(x - e^x-ix\xi\right)\,dx$$

Any hints or help will be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $u = e^x$ then your integral becomes
$$
\int_0^\infty e^{-u} u^{-i\xi} ~d u.
$$
This integral is the [Gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function). So
$$
\int_0^\infty e^{-u} u^{-i\xi} ~d u = \Gamma(1-i\xi).
$$
(I'm assuming $\xi$ is a real number?)